# Korganizer synchronization

Tags: synchronization, calendar

I use Korganizer in my main laptop and in my secondary laptop - both runs netrunner linux.

Recently the main went kaboom and i realize the necessity of having a way to synchronize my data accress devices.

I know that I can use google or outlook or ical or such big companies.

But what are my other options if I want :

1. To easily an seemlessly synchronize my PIM data across linux and hopefully Cyanogen mod;
2. To use aprefereablly free service;
3. To not use any company like Google due to privacy reasons

? Thank you for answers.